# Exchange 2010 Event ID 2159 showing up multiple times each day

Tags: active-directory, exchange, exchange-2010

I am getting a lot of `Event ID 2159` warnings on my Exchange 2010 server. When I navigate to the specified location in `ADSI Edit`, I don't see anything strange. The path is:

```
CN=Interop RGC,CN=Connections,CN=Exchange Routing Group (DWBGZMFD01QNBJR),CN=Routing Groups,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=First Organization,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=domainname,DC=com
```

The only orphaned server references I was able to find were in the path below, and there are only three `CN=SMTP` objects there, all of them pointing to the orphaned server. So is it safe to delete them?

```
CN=Connections,CN=First Organization,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=domainname,DC=com
```

Here are the details of the event ID 2159 warning:

Process edgetransport.exe () (PID=5212). Configuration object CN=Interop RGC,CN=Connections,CN=Exchange Routing Group (DWBGZMFD01QNBJR),CN=Routing Groups,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=First Organization,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=domainname,DC=com read from dc1.domainname.com failed validation and will be excluded from the result set.  Set event logging level for Validation category to Expert to get additional events about each failure.

Comment: We don't all have every single Event ID in existence memorized so how about posting the details of that Event ID, like the Source, details, etc.?

Comment: What does get-routinggroupconnector return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be just removing all routing group connectors which were still there from an Exchange 2003 server which was decommissioned years ago. 
The command I used:

```
Get-RoutingGroupConnector | Remove-RoutingGroupConnector
```